# Show that max $|f(x)| ≥ (c_0/8) (b − a)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

Let $f : [a, b] → R$ be continuous with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. Suppose that $f′′(x)$ exists with $|f′′(x)| ≥ c_0 > 0, ∀x ∈ (a, b),$ for some constant $c_0$. Prove that
max $|f(x)| ≥ (c_0/8) (b − a)^2$.

What I tried:

Let $M=max |f(x)|$ on $[a,b]$ be achieved at $x_0$. Then $f'(x_0)=0$ as $x_0$ will be the point of extrema. I then thought of using the Taylor's expansion around $x=x_0$ which gives $f(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+(x-x_0)^2/2 f''(t)$ for some $t$ between $x$ and $x_0$. As $f'(x_0)=0$ this reduces to $f(x)=M+(x-x_0)^2/2 f''(t)$. I can apply the absolute and on the second term, use the fact that $|f′′(x)| ≥ c_0$. But I don't know how that will give me the result.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: You haven't used $f(a) = f(b) = 0$

Comment: I tried using it by expanding f(x) around x=a and x=b but then that led me nowhere.

Comment: Oh wait! I can plug in a and b for x on the LHS!

Comment: By doing so, I got $|M| \geq (a-x_0)^2c_0/2$. Still a bit confused as to how to prove the given inequality.

Comment: @SC You are almost there. Note that either $|a-x_0|$ or $|b-x_0|$ must be $\geq \frac{(b-a)}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, as $|a-x_0|=|b-x_0|$, and hence $||≥(−_0)^2_0/2\geq (b-a)^2/4 *c_0 \geq (b-a)^2/8 *c_0$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note, however, that $|f(x_0)| = M$, not simply $f(x_0) = M$. So the equation $f(x) = M + \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2} f''(t)$ should be $f(x) = f(x_0) + \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2} f''(t)$.

Setting $x = a$ yields $$f(x_0) = -\frac{(x_0 - a)^2}{2}f''(t_1)$$ for some $t_1$ between $x_0$ and $a$. Similarly $f(x_0) = -\frac{(b - x_0)^2}{2} f''(t_2)$ for some $t_1$ between $x_0$ and $b$. Thus $$|f(x_0)| \ge \frac{c_0}{2}(x_0 - a)^2\quad \text{and}\quad |f(x_0)| \ge \frac{c_0}{2}(b - x_0)^2$$ Therefore, $$M\ge \frac{c_0}{2}\left[\frac{(x_0 - a)^2}{2} + \frac{(b - x_0)^2}{2}\right] \ge \frac{c_0}{2}\left[\frac{(x_0 - a) + (b - x_0)}{2}\right]^2 = \frac{c_0}{8}(b-a)^2$$ as desired.